# getting a value from a soap response in android ,

Tags: android

I'm using the below code to get the value from a response , but im getting the following error Network on main thread exception , however im sure that the url ,name space , method and soap action are correct as they are working in the browser , also i get an error in parsing SoapObject and soaSerializationEnvelope , how can i solve such issue or if i can have a simple example of parsing a soap request and getting the value of an item that would be excellent

public void test() {

textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

```
    SoapObject reSoapObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope soaSerializationEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);


    soaSerializationEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(reSoapObject);
    HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    String ip = null;

    try {
        httpTransportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, soaSerializationEnvelope);
        SoapObject soapObjectResultRoot = (SoapObject) soaSerializationEnvelope.bodyIn;

        Log.e(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", "Root elemtn body: "
                + soapObjectResultRoot.toString());

        SoapObject soapObjectGetProperty = (SoapObject) soapObjectResultRoot.getProperty("return");
        ip = soapObjectGetProperty.getProperty("return").toString();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    textView.setText(" \nIP --> " + ip);

}
```

Comment: I have answered with full example on this one... 
Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608701/android-how-to-pass-double-value-to-service-using-ksoap/11718868#11718868

Answer (score 0):

just read again very carefully the exception name and try to understand it's meaning:

```
Network on main thread exception
```

it means you're executing network operations, which, just like any other IO operation, takes several milliseconds to process awaiting for a hardware response, on the main thread (read: UI thread).

So it means you're blocking the UI thread and makes your app lag and run slow and nobody wants that.

Just use one of the several different threading methods. The most common one is the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), but if you want to explore further you can research on threads for lower level interaction, Loaders for activity life cycle managed with some nice auto data handling touches or Executors for higher level multi-threading control.